# Searching data stored in a tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have this data that is hierarchical and so I store it in a tree. I want to provide a search function to it. Do I have to create a binary tree for that? I don't want to have thousands of nodes twice. Isn't there a kind of tree that allows me to both store the data in the order given and also provide me the binary tree like efficient searching setup, with little overhead?

Any other data structure suggestion will also be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Some details: The tree is a very simple "hand made" tree that can be considered very very basic. The thing is, there are thousands of names and other text that will be entered as data that I want to search but I don't want to traverse the nodes in a traditional way and need a fast search like binary search.

Also, importantly, the user must be able to see the structure he has entered and NOT the sorted one. So I cant keep it sorted to support the search. That is why I said I don't want to have thousands of nodes twice.

Comment: Why do you think you will need the nodes twice? When you say  "I store it in a tree" - what kind of tree? What's preventing you from searching that directly? Basically, more detail needed.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a binary tree. It has to be a [*search* tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree). Binary trees per se don't give fast searches.

Comment: @Paul I have added some details to the question.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes OK, I meant search tree when I said binary tree like. Thanks for the info. I am new to data structures.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your trees hierarchy use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) to store pointers to vertexes: `std::map<SearchKeyType,Vertex*> M`.

Every time when you will add vertex to your tree you need to add it to your map too. It's very easy: `M[key]=&vertex`. To find an element use `M.find(key);`, or `M[key];` if you are sure that key exists.

If your tree has duplicate keys, then you should use a [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/).

Edit: If your key's size is too big, than you can use  pointer to key instead of key:

```
inline bool comparisonFunction(SearchKeyType * arg1,SearchKeyType * arg2);

std::map<SearchKeyType *, Vertex *, comparisonFunction> M;

inline bool comparisonFunction(SearchKeyType * arg1,SearchKeyType * arg2)
{
         return (*arg1)<(*arg2);
}
```

to search Element with value `V` you must write  following:

```
Vertex * v = M[&V]; // assuming that element V exists in M
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like for every node that I add to the tree, I'll have to store a pointer to that in the map, effectively duplicating the node count, albeit in another data structure. I mean, the map to maintain this pointer must create nodes internally. But that is what I want to avoid. Am I wrong in what I understood?

Comment: Yes, very much. I even mentioned it in the edit to the OP as it is very important. Data is shown in the UI.

Comment: @Dirt I edited my answer.  And yes, you can't do that without using more memory.